# Bitwise operator with taking input from user

Tags: c, scanf, bitwise-operators, unsigned-char, conversion-specifier

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char a,b;
   
    printf("Enter first number : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter 2nd number : ");

    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("a&b = %d\n", a&b);

    printf("a|b = %d\n", a|b); 

    printf("a^b = %d\n", a^b);
    
    printf("~a = %d\n",a = ~a);
    printf("b<<1 = %d\n", b<<1); 

    printf("b>>1 = %d\n", b>>1); 

    return 0;
}
```

i am taking input from user but i am getting wrong output how i modify i***

> `error`

---

Comment: `%d` is not the correct specifier for the variable you are passing to `scanf`, using the wrong specifier in scanf leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that can produce the output you claim it does.

Comment: You also forgot to mention what the *correct* output is.

Comment: This `printf("~a = %d\n", a = ~a);` is also strange, why not `printf("~a = %d\n", ~a);`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

These calls of `scanf`

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```

and

```
scanf("%d",&b);
```

use an incorrect format specification.

The variables `a` and `b` are declared as having the type `unsigned char`

```
unsigned char a,b;
```

If you want to enter integers in these variables you need to write

```
scanf("%hhu",&a);
```

and

```
scanf("%hhu",&b);
```

So your program will look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    unsigned char a, b;

    printf( "Enter first number : " );
    scanf( "%hhu", &a );

    printf( "Enter 2nd number : " );
    scanf( "%hhu", &b );

    printf( "a&b = %d\n", a & b );

    printf( "a|b = %d\n", a | b );

    printf( "a^b = %d\n", a ^ b );

    printf( "~a = %d\n", a = ~a );

    printf( "b<<1 = %d\n", b << 1 );

    printf( "b>>1 = %d\n", b >> 1 );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter first number : 10
Enter 2nd number : 15
a&b = 10
a|b = 15
a^b = 5
~a = 245
b<<1 = 30
b>>1 = 7
```